# How to toggle bash redirection behavior with a variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a bash script that logs all output to a file:

```
./Configure > "${LOGFILE}" 2>&1
make > "${LOGFILE}" 2>&1
```

How could I setup the logfile behavior using a variable? For example, if a variable `VERBOSE` is `TRUE`, the output should not be redirected, but if set to `FALSE`, it should be redirected to the log file (as shown above).

I'd like to implement this without a lot of if-else clauses. Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Note that `FALSE` is an awkward value in `bash`, because it evaluates to `true` when queried as in @DevSolar s example. It's often more compatible to just use `""` as a false value.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to simply set `LOGFILE` to `/dev/stdout` (or maybe `/dev/tty`), rather than the name of a file to log to, at least on Linux. Then your existing redirections would not need to be modified. It would modify the buffering characteristics for output a bit, but otherwise is pretty much equivalent to not redirecting...